# Mapbox GL map not moving while dragging it

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js, react-leaflet, mapbox-gl

I am facing following bug when using `mapbox-gl-leaflet`.

When I drag the map, **SOMETIMES** the markers move over the map.

- Other layers work perfectly. The problem seems related with Mapbox GL.
- I have tried different versions, no luck yet.
- Not sure where the bug comes from. My versions are:

```
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "react-leaflet": "2.8.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.12.0",
    "mapbox-gl-leaflet": "0.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
```

Is there any free of bug version?

[image]

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-typescript-forked-duckq4?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like using following version of the package fix the bug:

```
    "mapbox-gl": "2.0.0",
```